# How to run .sh file

Tags: java, linux, sh

I am using Ubuntu and just downloaded the jmonkey game engine.  Everything appears to be in a single .sh file.  I am not really sure how I am supposed to run this.

http://jmonkeyengine.com/

Answer (score 6):

Um...if it's not in your `$PATH`:

```
./your_shell_script.sh
```

Or if it's not in your `$PATH` and it's not executable:

```
sh your_shell_script.sh
```

Or if it's in your `$PATH`:

```
your_shell_script.sh
```

Comment: Do the second one if the file is not executable. Otherwise you need to have #!/bin/bash as the first line of the file, and then do chmod +x your_shell_script.sh

Comment: I moved the file into my home directory and made it executable.  It works now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: './FILE.sh' or 'sh FILE.sh'. If you can't execute it, chmod +x FILE.sh

Answer (score 0):

try
sh -x single .sh file (assuming the +x permissions are set).
Also I am assuming you probably need some jdk/jre installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ nohup ./your_file.sh <arguements> &
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick alternative to

```
sh my_bash_script.sh
```

is to use double dots as follows:

```
. ./my_bash_script.sh
```

This is useful if the file does not have the execute bit set.